# How to build python with --enable-framework (--enable-shared) on macos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to use PyInstaller to build a MultiOS application. The Project already has a virtual environment using the venv which comes with python by default (have not installed pyenv). I ran into multiple problems and searched a lot.
Finally I've come to the conclusion that the problem is my installed version of python does not have shared framework enabled and I have to rebuild my python? I actually have to no clue how to do that. Any help or a link of how to do it would really be appreciated. Thank you very much.

This is the error, which directed me here:

`If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with '--enable-shared' (or, '--enable-framework' on Darwin)`

Comment: How did you create the venv?

Comment: @Legorooj with pycharm virtual environment. I have a venv directory in my project I think it's with built in virtual environment that comes with python which I have to change source If I wanna work on that env.

Comment: pycharm uses the default `venv` module. How did you install python, and which exact version are you using?

Comment: @Legorooj I don't remember Exactly how I installed it, but as I have idle and python Launcher in my Launchpad I guess with installer which comes in the python.org website. It's 3.8.1

Comment: @Legorooj I have a found a link which explains how to do it but do I have to uninstall the previous one or I can build on top of it?

Comment: You can install multiple versions of python. You'll need to install 3.7; 3.8 is unsupported at the moment. We're working to fix this, but it's slow. Download the installer from python.org for 3.7, and see if that works. (Enable-Shared should be on by default)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using pyenv, this is what has worked for me:

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.6.15
```

Found [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2392).